# Validating xml against xsd but getting org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xmlschema

I am trying to validate XML against a XSD file in Java.

This is my code:

```
public static InputStream inputStreamFromClasspath(String path) {
    return Utils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
}   

public static boolean validateXMLSchema() throws SAXException, IOException {

    InputStream xsd = inputStreamFromClasspath("/xml/students_xsd.xml");
    InputStream xml = inputStreamFromClasspath("/xml/students.xml");
    SchemaFactory factory =
                SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsd));
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.validate(new StreamSource(xml));
    return true;
}
```

But I am getting an error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

Code reference: [Validating XML against XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815579/validating-xml-against-xsd)

My Students xml file is:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>

<class>
    <student rollno = "393">
        <firstname>Dinkar</firstname>
        <lastname>Kad</lastname>
        <nickname>Dinkar</nickname>
        <marks>85</marks>
    </student>

    <student rollno = "493">
        <firstname>Vaneet</firstname>
        <lastname>Gupta</lastname>
        <nickname>Vinni</nickname>
        <marks>95</marks>
    </student>

    <student rollno = "593">
        <firstname>Jasvir</firstname>
        <lastname>Singh</lastname>
        <nickname>Jazz</nickname>
        <marks>90</marks>
    </student>
</class>
```

And the xsd file is:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name = 'class'>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name = 'student' type = 'StudentType' minOccurs = '0'
                            maxOccurs = 'unbounded' />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name = "StudentType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name = "firstname" type = "xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name = "lastname" type = "xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name = "nickname" type = "xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name = "marks" type = "xs:positiveInteger"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name = 'rollno' type = 'xs:positiveInteger'/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Not sure where I am getting wrong, any suggestions will be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One other thing:

```
    InputStream xsd = inputStreamFromClasspath("/xml/students_xsd.xml");
    return Utils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
```

- A ClassLoader uses an absolute path without preceding `/`.
- A class uses a possibly relative path (relative to its package), and for absolute paths need a preceding `/`.

Either (my preference, better with modular java)

```
    InputStream xsd = inputStreamFromClasspath("/xml/students_xsd.xml");
    return Utils.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
```

or (needing correction of all calls)

```
    InputStream xsd = inputStreamFromClasspath("xml/students_xsd.xml");
    return Utils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
```

You got a `null` resource because of that slash.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was in the schema it was xs, should be xsd. But this was a problem too.

Comment: @Rumi: Hmm, are you sure about that?  Your XSD defines and uses an `xs:schema` root element with `xmlns:xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`, which is fine instead of defining `xsd` as the namespace prefix.    It would seem more likely to me that you're messing up with specifying the XSD due to one or more issues that Joop has indicated.

Comment: You are right, I was messing up the file path, Thank you.

Comment: It’s better to use Class.getResource(AsStream) than the ClassLoader methods.  In modular applications, they have slightly different behavior.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68314700/why-java-cannot-read-same-resource-file-when-module-info-is-added/68321325#68321325.